# Eclipse complying "Unresolved generator name" but all works fine

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, ubuntu

I use a hibernate @GenericGenerator(name="myGenerator") to setup a generator and use it with @GeneratedValue(generator = "myGenerator").

The application **runs fine**, but Eclipse reports an error of **'Unresolved generator name "myGenerator"'.**

Is there either a way to disable this error check or to configure the project so that it recognized the "MySeq" generator?

**PREVIOUS ENVIRONMENT:**

- **Windows** + Java5 + Eclipse = No additional config for this bug

**ACTUAL ENVIRONMENT:**

- **Linux** + Java5 + Eclipse - 
  I'm using Linux+Eclipse now on my environment and in all GenericGenerator of my classes start to bug me up.

I don't know if this is due to my change of environment or Eclipse version.

Thanks in advance for any tip provided.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a dummy generator plugin as a placeholder.  There's a sample "Plug-in with an incremental project builder" that should get you most of the way there... sounds like you'd just need to do some pruning.

In Helios, you do the following:

1. File
2. New
3. Project...
4. Plug-in Development
5. Plug-in Project
6. Give it a name
7. "next" twice
8. Templates
9. "Plug-in with an incremental project builder"

Comment: Mark, I'll check this tomorrow, but thanks in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is quite simple. The error is caused by the built-in Java Persistence Validator. In order to prevent Eclipse showing the error you just have to set the validation level for "Unresolved generator name" to warning or lower. See "Java Persistence - Errors/Warnings - Queries and generators" in Eclipse preferences dialogue.